# Redirect my website .com to .net

Tags: redirect, dns

I have `.com` website and `2` other websites who redirect to `.com`, now i want redirect `.com` to `.net` and don't know if i need redirect this `2` websites also or is enough if i redirect only `.com` to `.net` ?

Comment: If a visitor arrives to a web then it will be redirect to .com and then it will be redirect to .net . However It isn't a good practice because redirects need some time.

Comment: @ganchito55 yes i understand better redirect all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by redirecting .com to .net you not need to redirect other two domain if your .com domain not expired after time...
but it's better to redirect all domain directly to .net ... because of faster loading of main page you need to remove unnecessary redirects... 
for example .us to .net is better than .us to .com to .net

Comment: i need redirect in google webmaster tools or simple 301 redirect in .htaccess is enough ?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should redirect all domains to the new IP where you have the .net hosting.

You can usually do this in a control panel from your domain provider.

For example if you actually have this:
web.com -> IP
web.1 -> IP
web.2 -> IP

then you should have:
web.net -> newIP
web.com -> newIP
web.1 -> newIP
web.2 -> newIP

**The fastest way for redirection is to change the IP in DNS**.

Comment: is not better 301 redirect ?

Comment: @mat.534 as you can see [here](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection) 302 and 301 don't pass the 100% link juice.